# jQuery - Parsing JSON file based on mouse click

Tags: jquery

This is more of a theory question rather than a specific programming problem.

What I'm trying to do is create a World of Tanks player "search engine" with the following steps:

1. Enter the username of the player
2. Parse the JSON object of players with similar names and append it to the page
3. Based on the name the user clicks, clear the page and populate it with the JSON object for that specific player.

I can successfully generate the URL that returns the JSON file of the player, but I'm having trouble figuring out a way to render that information to the page.

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K3NBB/) of all the code.

This function creates a list of all the matching players and turns their name into a link to the JSON file.

```
$.getJSON(searchURL, function(data){
        $.each(data, function(key, value){
            if(typeof value === 'object'){
                for(var i=0; i < data.count; i++){
                    var fullPlayerURL = "<p class='entry'>" + "<a>" + key +
                        "Nickname - " + value + "</a>" + "</p>";
                    $('#results').append(fullPlayerURL);
                }
            }
        });
}); //end getJSON
```

My question is, what would be the best way to generate the player's data based on which name the user clicks (instead of following the link to the JSON file)?

Thanks!

Comment: where do you want display the details

Comment: @ArunPJohny I was thinking of appending them below the `#results` div, but I'm open to suggestions!

Comment: There is a problem in the entry click handler.... to fetch the json data http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xj27w/1/

Comment: You will need to create a template on what kind of markup is required

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xj27w/2/